# How does the code in App.css gets included when exporting default App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-import, css-import

I am new to react (Javascript as well), I got this doubt reagarding the output when rendering the React Component-> `App` of the template code generated using 'create-react-app'.

Here is the App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

File directory system :

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── serviceWorker.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

In the file `App.js` , `export default App;` exports `App` which is then being imported in `index.js` which uses `ReactDOM.render` to render the `App`. I am having difficulty in understanding how the code in `App.css` gets used/imported in `index.js`? Afterall only `App` is getting exported (as default) which is not visibly using any CSS code inside it. Am I missing or interpreting something wrong here?

Thanks for reading.

  **Edit :** 
Specifically, I want to know how does React applies CSS (which are imported) to the components defined in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming to your statement:

```
I am having difficulty in understanding how the code in App.css gets used/imported in index.js?
```

Actually, You want to know, how the CSS code written in `App.css` is applied to `App` Component. The answer is straight forward, It is because your `App.js` is using that CSS file since `App.css` is imported  in your `App.js` file

```
`import "./App.css";`
```

All the CSS is first being applied to `App` Component and only when you import and Render `App` in `index.js` using

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
  <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

React renders your `App` component along with all the CSS that is provided in `App.css`.

**Now addressing your other statment:**

```
Afterall only App is getting exported (as default) which is not visibly using 
any CSS code inside it.
```

Well I have to say, this is not a right statement as `App` Component is using CSS written in `App.css`. In your JSX you have returned the following:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

You see `className="App"`, so `App` here is your `class selector` and the CSS for this is this.

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

Try using any other CSS property here and you will see the changes reflecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you have said : "All the CSS is first being applied to App Component", how does React "applies" css to components? Ex : If I am importing multiple css files in my script, then how does React applies the css scripts to various different components (if present)?

Comment: As you know React is a single page application, underneath the hood all our components are rendered in 1 html file in the <div class="root"></div>. Now Webpack  (which is already setup by react for us ) takes care of bundling all the CSS files into one CSS file. In the end it is just 1 html file and 1 css file. our className gets changed into class in our HTML file, and we refer to our CSS file (1 CSS file) quite comfortably. :) Any other doubts do write back.